# System.Data.Entity.Core.MetadataException: 'Schema specified is not valid.

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, edmx

I'm creating a login window and problem appears when pressing submit button after entering wrong credentials.
Here is my view

```
@model ProjectyMcProjectface.Models.RegisteredUser
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Login page</title>
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/LoginVisuals")
</head>
<body>
    <div id="LoginWrapper"> 
        @using (Html.BeginForm("Authorize", "Login",FormMethod.Post))
        {
            <table id="LoginTable">
                <tr>
                    <td>@Html.LabelFor(model => model.UserName)</td>
                    <td>@Html.EditorFor(model => model.UserName)</td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td>@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.UserName)</td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td>@Html.LabelFor(model => model.PassWord)</td>
                    <td>@Html.EditorFor(model => model.PassWord)</td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td>@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PassWord)</td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2"><label class="field-validation-error">@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.LoginErrorMessage)</label></td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td>
                    <input type="submit" value="Login" />
                    <input type="reset" value="Clear" />
                    </td>
                </tr>

            </table>
        }
    </div>

    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/ValidationScripts")
</body>
</html>
```

my registered user model

```
public partial class RegisteredUser
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("User Name")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "This field is required to be filled")]
        public string UserName { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        [DisplayName("Password")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "This field is required to be filled")]
        public string PassWord { get; set; }

        public string LoginErrorMessage { get; set; }
    }
```

and my login controller

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Authorize(ProjectyMcProjectface.Models.RegisteredUser userModel)
{
    using (InternalDBEntities1 db = new InternalDBEntities1())
    {
        var userDetails = db.RegisteredUsers.Where(x => x.UserName == userModel.UserName && x.PassWord == userModel.PassWord).FirstOrDefault();
        if (userDetails == null)
        {
            userModel.LoginErrorMessage = "Your password or user name is incorrect";
            return View("Index", "Login", userModel);
        }

    }

        return View();
}
```

the error fires in line

```
var userDetails = db.RegisteredUsers.Where(x => x.UserName == userModel.UserName && x.PassWord == userModel.PassWord).FirstOrDefault();
```

and says

> The mapping of CLR type to EDM type is ambiguous because multiple CLR
>   types match the EDM type 'RegisteredUser'. Previously found CLR type
>   'ProjectyMcProjectface.RegisteredUser', newly found CLR type
>   'ProjectyMcProjectface.Models.RegisteredUser'.'

How can I solve this?

Comment: From the error you posted it looks like you have a conflict of two classes. They are both named RegisteredUser. One resides in the `ProjectyMcProjectface` and the other in `ProjectyMcProjectface.Models`. That's what is causing the ambiguity. I will suggest you rename one of them

Comment: @jamiedanq yes, thank you, it worked!

Comment: Glad it solved it!

Comment: Can you please mark my comment as helpful

Comment: @jamiedanq I'm afraid I don't know how

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be path of Edm has been changed some how. Please check the edm location whether it is ok and clean and rebuild the project